# Removing old server branches in git - how do I find them?

Tags: git

Our team allows people to push personal and feature branches to a server for things they are working on. This is all properly namespaced, e.g. personal/sally/somebug and features/foos etc.

But the server is getting a bit full of them and many are old and unused. I want to produce a report of all branches showing the last activity on a branch, sorted by date. I can email out the report to devs so they can delete their old branches.

I also want the report to show if the branch was merged onto our mainline branch or it has orphan commits which are nowhere else.

Is there any simple way to achieve this using git or a combination of git and some scripts?

Comment: You can check if a remote branch is merged or not using `git branch -r --merged` and `git branch -r --no-merged`

Comment: `git for-each-ref refs/remotes --format='%(authordate) %(refname)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For listing the time of the last commit on each remote branch probably this is the easiest one:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes --sort=authordate --format='%(authordate:iso8601) %(refname)'
```

To list all branches already merged into branch `mainline` you can use:

```
git branch -r --merged mainline
```

Also have a look at `git help for-each-ref` for a very complex report example.

Comment: Thanks - I think this is just what I need. Might need to glue it together with perl but I have the data.